# ¿Cómo puedo saber que tipo de dato ha introducido un usuario en un programa de C?

Tags: c

Seré más específico. Estoy ayudando a crear un programa de C y me he visto en ascuas. Una vez que el usuario introduce un dato con `scanf()`, quisiera comprobar que el dato introducido es tipo int y no char. Estuve investigando con `typeof()`, al estilo de como lo realizo en JS, pero no obtuve ningún resultado satisfactorio. ¿Algún método para validar que el dato es únicamente numérico y no letras o carácteres especiales?

Comment: Debes agregar a la pregunta lo que tengas hecho.

Comment: Con scanf lo veo dificil, deberias usar  una función como gets o fgets, esas funciones lo que hacen es leer caracteres hasta encontrar un carácter de retorno de carro (comúnmente un enter introducido desde teclado) sobre la cadena puedes revisar si es un entero, un flotante o una cadena como tal y hacer la correspondiente conversión.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Una vez que el usuario introduce un dato con scanf(), quisiera comprobar que el dato introducido es tipo int y no char.

La [documentación de `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) nos indica que el valor de retorno de la función es la cantidad de argumentos leídos, si no lee ninguno devolverá un cero.

Así que si le pedimos leer un número (`%d`) pero no le pasamos un número, entonces fallará:

```
int dato;

if (scanf("%d", &dato))
    printf("Se ha leído %d correctamente\n", dato);
else
    printf("El dato introducido no es un numero\n");
```

Si se introduce `aa` como dato el programa anterior mostrará:

> ```
> El dato introducido no es un numero
> ```

Pero si se introduce `1a`, el programa mostrará

> ```
> Se ha leído 1 correctamente
> ```

Si eso no te interesa, comprueba que después de la lectura no queden datos restantes:

```
int dato;

if (scanf("%d", &dato) && feof(stdin))
    printf("Se ha leído %d correctamente\n", dato);
else
    printf("El dato introducido no es un numero\n");
```

En este caso, introduciendo `1a` la salida es:

> ```
> El dato introducido no es un numero
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xDsIwDEXn@hRWUatEAgRzERsnYGWJEpdGSm2UJiyII3EKDlbSTmy2v9/TtzsbDN/neePZhuwIT1NyXvbDGcBzwtF4Vk/xTsMLquXiTJIOytyjmqzhXtWNq7fYLoHGtsWepFeLhrWGqnrEgpWvK@FgMND34wQbh1ZiJJvMSJzoxkWxGjqoKEz0B17CmmDZorhsfeFZkCbMjJxHilJwvZSKlHJkPHTwnuejgR8)</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

¿Has intentado algo como esto? -->  `if(typeof(dato) == double){...}`

Podrías crear un método en C que haga lo mismo.

```
void mostrarTipo(){
   int dato;
   printf("Teclea un dato:");
   scanf("%d",&dato);

  if(typeof(dato) == int){...}
  if(typeof(dato) == double){...}
}
```

Si esto no te sirve, hay muchos recursos en Internet donde buscar lo que quieres obtener. Yo he encontrado algunas cosas como:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280055/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-of-a-certain-type-compare-two-types-in-c
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804371/syntax-and-sample-usage-of-generic-in-c11/17290414#17290414
3. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic

Específicamente los dos primeros enlaces podrían servirte.

Comment: No respondas a preguntas que no tengan un código (eso denota el esfuerzo y dedicación del OP).

Comment: dado que has declarado `int dato`, `typeof(dato)` devolvera **siempre** `int`. En C++ los tipos están para algo...